# Jquery Checkbox Input Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="compare[]" value="<?php echo $product_id  ?>" />
```

Now, I want to let my users select minimum three and maximum three options from the above check box. Breaking of any of the rules would give a message.

Would you please kindly help me how to do that with Jquery?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why is the `name` of the checkbox "compare[]"? Why the need for the brackets? I hope you don't think that by adding brackets to the name of an input that it'll make multiple inputs...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 1 solution

```
var $chkbox = $('input[name=compare]');
$chkbox.click(function (e) {
    if ($chkbox.filter(':checked').length > 3) {
        e.target.checked = false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H96nz/

```
var $chkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$chkbox.click(function (e) {
    if ($chkbox.filter(':checked').length > 3) {
        e.target.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Trevor for you reply. Your script is not working, may be because my fieldname is--  name="compare[]"

Comment: Well, change the name or use a different selector. Either way, this is your solution. You may need to alter some things, but it does work. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your checkbox's using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), checking for checked items and adding checks to a count. Then if the count is not equal to 3 you can output the validation error message.

```
$(function(){
$("#frm").submit(function(){
    var checkCount = 0;
    var min = 3;
    var max = 3;

    // iterate over checkbox's using jquery each()
    // use jquery's attribute contains selector ( http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ )
    // to grab the compare portion of the checkbox field name
    $("input[name*='compare']").each(function(k, v) {

    // increment check count when a checked checkbox is found
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        checkCount++;
    });

    //validate checkbox count against predefined range
    if(checkCount < min || checkCount > max)
    {
        console.log("Checkbox Validation Failed");
        return false;
    }
    else
        console.log("Checkbox Validation Passed");

});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed the link that you gave and I tried to understand the example given there, but as it turned out I have no clue what they are saying . Would you please kindly explain me how to do this when your fieldname is like-- fieldname[] ?? Thanks :)

Comment: Code example with comments now included